# SQL Server 2019 service terminated unexpectedly at startup but manually starts

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I've had a SQL Server 2019 server working great for the past few months, but it started stopping by itself since last Friday. This morning, I installed latest cumulative update on it.

Here is my version

> Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU8-GDR) (KB4583459) - 15.0.4083.2 (X64)   Nov  2 2020 18:35:09   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0  (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

I've also had the problem with SQL Server 2019 Standard edition (RTM-CU8-GDR).

Each time, a minidump was created. After analyzing the dumps, I can see a kernel base exception.

[image: KernelBaseException]

This server runs only SQL Server, I have nothing more running on the machine.

In SQL's log file I see the dump being taken just after this message.

[image: error log]

In the Windows Event Viewer, I only have an error saying that SQL is stopping.

[image: event Viewer]

And just before that error, I have tree "Windows Error reporting" error about SQLException64.

[image: Event viewer error reporting]

Restarting the SQL Server doesn't change anything. But, if I open SQL Management Console and I start the SQL Service, it starts just fine.

I don't really know where to check, how to diagnose it further.

Here is the mini dump file.

```
2021-01-18 10:15:18.56 spid58      ex_terminator: Possible termination due to exception during stack unwinding.
2021-01-18 10:15:18.56 spid58      CImageHelper::Init () Version-specific dbghelp.dll is not used
2021-01-18 10:15:18.56 spid58      Using 'dbghelp.dll' version '4.0.5'
2021-01-18 10:15:18.56 spid58      **Dump thread - spid = 0, EC = 0x000001B929A93670
2021-01-18 10:15:18.56 spid58      ***Stack Dump being sent to E:\SQL Databases 2019\MSSQL15.SQL2019\MSSQL\LOG\SQLDump0002.txt
2021-01-18 10:15:18.56 spid58      *     *******************************************************************************
2021-01-18 10:15:18.56 spid58      *
2021-01-18 10:15:18.56 spid58      * BEGIN STACK DUMP:
2021-01-18 10:15:18.56 spid58      *   01/18/21 10:15:18 spid 58
2021-01-18 10:15:18.56 spid58      *
2021-01-18 10:15:18.56 spid58      * ex_terminator - Last chance exception handling
2021-01-18 10:15:18.56 spid58      *
2021-01-18 10:15:18.56 spid58      * Input Buffer 255 bytes -
2021-01-18 10:15:18.56 spid58      *                     16 00 00 00 12 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
2021-01-18 10:15:18.56 spid58      *      ÿÿ      çž     Ð 01 00 00 00 ff ff 0a 00 02 00 00 00 e7 9e01 09 04 d0
2021-01-18 10:15:18.56 spid58      *    ž                00 00 9e 01 0d 00 0a 00 a0 00 20 00 a0 00 20 00 a0 00
2021-01-18 10:15:18.56 spid58      *                W A  20 00 a0 00 20 00 a0 00 20 00 a0 00 20 00 57 00 41 00
2021-01-18 10:15:18.56 spid58      *  I T F O R (        49 00 54 00 46 00 4f 00 52 00 28 00 0d 00 0a 00 a0 00
2021-01-18 10:15:18.56 spid58      *                     20 00 a0 00 20 00 a0 00 20 00 a0 00 20 00 a0 00 20 00
2021-01-18 10:15:18.56 spid58      *              R E C  a0 00 20 00 a0 00 20 00 a0 00 20 00 52 00 45 00 43 00
2021-01-18 10:15:18.56 spid58      *  E I V E   c o n v  45 00 49 00 56 00 45 00 20 00 63 00 6f 00 6e 00 76 00
2021-01-18 10:15:18.56 spid58      *  e r s a t i o n _  65 00 72 00 73 00 61 00 74 00 69 00 6f 00 6e 00 5f 00
2021-01-18 10:15:18.56 spid58      *  h a n d l e , s e  68 00 61 00 6e 00 64 00 6c 00 65 00 2c 00 73 00 65 00
2021-01-18 10:15:18.56 spid58      *  r v i c e _ n a m  72 00 76 00 69 00 63 00 65 00 5f 00 6e 00 61 00 6d 00
2021-01-18 10:15:18.56 spid58      *  e , m e s s a g e  65 00 2c 00 6d 00 65 00 73 00 73 00 61 00 67 00 65 00
2021-01-18 10:15:18.56 spid58      *  _ t y p e _ n a m  5f 00 74 00 79 00 70 00 65 00 5f 00 6e 00 61 00 6d 00
2021-01-18 10:15:18.56 spid58      *  e , m e s s a g e  65 00 2c 00 6d 00 65 00 73 00 73 00 61 00 67 00 65 00
2021-01-18 10:15:18.56 spid58      *  _ b o d y          5f 00 62 00 6f 00 64 00 79 00 a0 00 0d 00 0a 00 a0 00
2021-01-18 10:15:18.56 spid58      *                     20 00 a0 00 20 00 a0 00 20 00 a0 00 20 00 a0 00 20 00
2021-01-18 10:15:18.56 spid58      *              F R O  a0 00 20 00 a0 00 20 00 a0 00 20 00 46 00 52 00 4f 00
2021-01-18 10:15:18.56 spid58      *  M   d b o . B r o  4d 00 20 00 64 00 62 00 6f 00 2e 00 42 00 72 00 6f 00
2021-01-18 10:15:18.56 spid58      *  k e r F o r m F i  6b 00 65 00 72 00 46 00 6f 00 72 00 6d 00 46 00 69 00
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *  e l d s R e q u e  65 00 6c 00 64 00 73 00 52 00 65 00 71 00 75 00 65 00
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *  s t M e s s a g e  73 00 74 00 4d 00 65 00 73 00 73 00 61 00 67 00 65 00
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *  s                  73 00 0d 00 0a 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *              ) ,    20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 29 00 2c 00 20 00
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *  t i m e o u t   @  74 00 69 00 6d 00 65 00 6f 00 75 00 74 00 20 00 40 00
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *  W a i t T i m e o  57 00 61 00 69 00 74 00 54 00 69 00 6d 00 65 00 6f 00
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *  u t   ç$   Ð  $ @  75 00 74 00 00 00 e7 24 00 09 04 d0 00 00 24 00 40 00
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *  W a i t T i m e o  57 00 61 00 69 00 74 00 54 00 69 00 6d 00 65 00 6f 00
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *  u t   f l o a t  @ 75 00 74 00 20 00 66 00 6c 00 6f 00 61 00 74 00 0c 40
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *   W a i t T i m e o 00 57 00 61 00 69 00 74 00 54 00 69 00 6d 00 65 00 6f
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *   u t  m       Lí@  00 75 00 74 00 00 6d 08 08 00 00 00 00 00 4c ed 40
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *  
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *  MODULE                          BASE      END       SIZE
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * sqlservr                       00007FF688800000  00007FF68889DFFF  0009e000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * ntdll                          00007FFCA0380000  00007FFCA056CFFF  001ed000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * KERNEL32                       00007FFC9FF10000  00007FFC9FFC2FFF  000b3000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * KERNELBASE                     00007FFC9CE60000  00007FFC9D0F4FFF  00295000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * CRYPT32                        00007FFC9D240000  00007FFC9D41BFFF  001dc000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * ucrtbase                       00007FFC9C450000  00007FFC9C549FFF  000fa000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * MSASN1                         00007FFC9C400000  00007FFC9C411FFF  00012000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * ADVAPI32                       00007FFC9FD10000  00007FFC9FDB2FFF  000a3000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * msvcrt                         00007FFC9FE70000  00007FFC9FF0DFFF  0009e000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * sechost                        00007FFC9D7B0000  00007FFC9D84EFFF  0009f000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * pdh                            00007FFC985D0000  00007FFC9861CFFF  0004d000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * RPCRT4                         00007FFCA0230000  00007FFCA034FFFF  00120000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * NETAPI32                       00007FFC97F00000  00007FFC97F16FFF  00017000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * ole32                          00007FFC9FBB0000  00007FFC9FD05FFF  00156000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * combase                        00007FFC9F380000  00007FFC9F6ADFFF  0032e000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * bcryptPrimitives               00007FFC9D420000  00007FFC9D49EFFF  0007f000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * GDI32                          00007FFC9F9A0000  00007FFC9F9C8FFF  00029000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * gdi32full                      00007FFC9C550000  00007FFC9C6EBFFF  0019c000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * msvcp_win                      00007FFC9D4F0000  00007FFC9D58FFFF  000a0000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * USER32                         00007FFC9F9D0000  00007FFC9FB66FFF  00197000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * win32u                         00007FFC9CE40000  00007FFC9CE5FFFF  00020000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * SQLOS                          00007FFC92760000  00007FFC92767FFF  00008000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * sqlTsEs                        00007FFC8DE10000  00007FFC8E6DAFFF  008cb000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * sqldk                          00007FFC8B2C0000  00007FFC8B7ECFFF  0052d000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * OLEAUT32                       00007FFCA0030000  00007FFCA00F3FFF  000c4000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * opends60                       00007FFC92750000  00007FFC92758FFF  00009000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * svl                            00007FFC92720000  00007FFC9274CFFF  0002d000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * qds                            00007FFC8B0F0000  00007FFC8B21AFFF  0012b000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * MSVCP140                       00007FFC947A0000  00007FFC9483AFFF  0009b000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * MPR                            00007FFC94AF0000  00007FFC94B0AFFF  0001b000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * VCRUNTIME140                   00007FFC94730000  00007FFC94745FFF  00016000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * sqlmin                         00007FFC8E6E0000  00007FFC91720FFF  03041000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * WINMM                          00007FFC8B0C0000  00007FFC8B0E3FFF  00024000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * WININET                        00007FFC8ABD0000  00007FFC8B0B0FFF  004e1000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * WS2_32                         00007FFC9F8D0000  00007FFC9F93CFFF  0006d000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * WINMMBASE                      00007FFC8ABA0000  00007FFC8ABCCFFF  0002d000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * cfgmgr32                       00007FFC9D4A0000  00007FFC9D4E9FFF  0004a000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * sqllang                        00007FFC8B7F0000  00007FFC8DE05FFF  02616000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * Secur32                        00007FFC97890000  00007FFC9789BFFF  0000c000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * WINHTTP                        00007FFC97D90000  00007FFC97E83FFF  000f4000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * secforwarder                   00007FFC8AAA0000  00007FFC8AAB0FFF  00011000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * ODBC32                         00007FFC8AAE0000  00007FFC8AB93FFF  000b4000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * bcrypt                         00007FFC9D160000  00007FFC9D185FFF  00026000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * WINTRUST                       00007FFC9D100000  00007FFC9D158FFF  00059000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * USERENV                        00007FFC9C2B0000  00007FFC9C2D8FFF  00029000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * profapi                        00007FFC9C420000  00007FFC9C443FFF  00024000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * ncrypt                         00007FFC9BE50000  00007FFC9BE75FFF  00026000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * AUTHZ                          00007FFC9B270000  00007FFC9B2BAFFF  0004b000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * XmlLite                        00007FFC97F20000  00007FFC97F59FFF  0003a000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * NETUTILS                       00007FFC9B9B0000  00007FFC9B9BDFFF  0000e000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * NTASN1                         00007FFC9BE10000  00007FFC9BE4BFFF  0003c000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * dhcpcsvc                       00007FFC984D0000  00007FFC984EBFFF  0001c000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * NSI                            00007FFC9F750000  00007FFC9F757FFF  00008000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * DPAPI                          00007FFC9C170000  00007FFC9C179FFF  0000a000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * SSPICLI                        00007FFC9C280000  00007FFC9C2AEFFF  0002f000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * SAMCLI                         00007FFC9B6D0000  00007FFC9B6E7FFF  00018000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * LOGONCLI                       00007FFC9B9C0000  00007FFC9B9FFFFF  00040000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * psapi                          00007FFC9D5B0000  00007FFC9D5B7FFF  00008000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * kernel.appcore                 00007FFC9C3E0000  00007FFC9C3F0FFF  00011000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * instapi150                     00007FFC86B80000  00007FFC86B93FFF  00014000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * CRYPTSP                        00007FFC9D590000  00007FFC9D5A6FFF  00017000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * rsaenh                         00007FFC9B4B0000  00007FFC9B4E2FFF  00033000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * CRYPTBASE                      00007FFC9BD50000  00007FFC9BD5BFFF  0000c000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * imagehlp                       00007FFC9F6B0000  00007FFC9F6CCFFF  0001d000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * gpapi                          00007FFC9ADB0000  00007FFC9ADD1FFF  00022000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * wkscli                         00007FFC98A70000  00007FFC98A86FFF  00017000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * cscapi                         00007FFC93490000  00007FFC934A1FFF  00012000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * sqlevn70                       000001AC0BBE0000  000001AC0BF1BFFF  0033c000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * CLUSAPI                        00007FFC92B20000  00007FFC92C27FFF  00108000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * DNSAPI                         00007FFC9B8E0000  00007FFC9B9A5FFF  000c6000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * IPHLPAPI                       00007FFC9B8A0000  00007FFC9B8DCFFF  0003d000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * RESUTILS                       00007FFC92C30000  00007FFC92CCDFFF  0009e000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * VERSION                        00007FFC95770000  00007FFC95779FFF  0000a000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * hkruntime                      00007FFC82C60000  00007FFC82F32FFF  002d3000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * dbghelp                        00007FFC96FD0000  00007FFC971BCFFF  001ed000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * hkcompile                      00007FFC82420000  00007FFC8255FFFF  00140000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * hkengine                       00007FFC82560000  00007FFC82C55FFF  006f6000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * SHLWAPI                        00007FFC9F810000  00007FFC9F861FFF  00052000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * ncryptprov                     00007FFC94FD0000  00007FFC95029FFF  0005a000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * msv1_0                         00007FFC9BB00000  00007FFC9BB75FFF  00076000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * NtlmShared                     00007FFC9BAF0000  00007FFC9BAFCFFF  0000d000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * cryptdll                       00007FFC9BBF0000  00007FFC9BC04FFF  00015000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * kerberos                       00007FFC9BC40000  00007FFC9BD43FFF  00104000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * schannel                       00007FFC9B3E0000  00007FFC9B463FFF  00084000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * SECURITY                       000001C5C6D50000  000001C5C6D52FFF  00003000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * MSCOREE                        00007FFC959E0000  00007FFC95A43FFF  00064000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * mscoreei                       00007FFC8B220000  00007FFC8B2BBFFF  0009c000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * SqlServerSpatial150            00007FFC82370000  00007FFC82411FFF  000a2000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * clbcatq                        00007FFC9FDC0000  00007FFC9FE61FFF  000a2000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * msxml3                         00007FFC82130000  00007FFC8236CFFF  0023d000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * msoledbsql                     00007FFC81E80000  00007FFC82122FFF  002a3000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * COMDLG32                       00007FFCA0100000  00007FFCA0226FFF  00127000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * shcore                         00007FFC9F760000  00007FFC9F807FFF  000a8000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * SHELL32                        00007FFC9DE80000  00007FFC9F379FFF  014fa000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * windows.storage                00007FFC9C6F0000  00007FFC9CE3AFFF  0074b000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * powrprof                       00007FFC9C380000  00007FFC9C3DCFFF  0005d000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * COMCTL32                       00007FFC81DD0000  00007FFC81E78FFF  000a9000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * MSOLEDBSQLR                    000001C5D6F10000  000001C5D6F31FFF  00022000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * dhcpcsvc6                      00007FFC98A50000  00007FFC98A65FFF  00016000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * sqlncli11                      00007FFC81A70000  00007FFC81DC2FFF  00353000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * MSVCR100                       0000000064820000  00000000648F1FFF  000d2000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * ualapi                         00007FFC95030000  00007FFC95049FFF  0001a000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * ntmarta                        00007FFC9B0C0000  00007FFC9B0F0FFF  00031000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * ESENT                          00007FFC94CA0000  00007FFC94FC6FFF  00327000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * SQLNCLIR11                     000001C5D6FE0000  000001C5D7017FFF  00038000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * netbios                        00007FFC92840000  00007FFC9284BFFF  0000c000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * sqlnclirda11                   00000000644C0000  0000000064818FFF  00359000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * SQLNCLIRDAR11                  000001C5D7020000  000001C5D7057FFF  00038000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * clr                            00007FFC8A030000  00007FFC8AA1BFFF  009ec000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * MSVCR120_CLR0400               00007FFC89F30000  00007FFC8A026FFF  000f7000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * mscorlib.ni                    00007FFC88980000  00007FFC89F10FFF  01591000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * SqlAccess                      00007FFC819F0000  00007FFC81A65FFF  00076000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * clrjit                         00007FFC86BB0000  00007FFC86CDAFFF  0012b000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * BatchParser                    00007FFC81430000  00007FFC81459FFF  0002a000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * SRVCLI                         00007FFC98530000  00007FFC98555FFF  00026000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * mskeyprotect                   00007FFC7DC40000  00007FFC7DC54FFF  00015000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * mswsock                        00007FFC9BB80000  00007FFC9BBE6FFF  00067000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * ntdsapi                        00007FFC95200000  00007FFC95227FFF  00028000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * DSPARSE                        00007FFC95E90000  00007FFC95E9CFFF  0000d000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * rasadhlp                       00007FFC96B60000  00007FFC96B69FFF  0000a000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * fwpuclnt                       00007FFC98900000  00007FFC98978FFF  00079000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * ncryptsslp                     00007FFC7DC90000  00007FFC7DCB3FFF  00024000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * xpsqlbot                       00007FFC81750000  00007FFC81759FFF  0000a000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * xpstar                         00007FFC816D0000  00007FFC81741FFF  00072000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * SQLSCM                         00007FFC819A0000  00007FFC819B3FFF  00014000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * xpstar                         000001C75A220000  000001C75A22CFFF  0000d000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * SAMLIB                         00007FFC971C0000  00007FFC971E2FFF  00023000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * xplog70                        00007FFC987F0000  00007FFC98805FFF  00016000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * xplog70                        000001C75A340000  000001C75A343FFF  00004000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * Sort00060101                   00007FFC972A0000  00007FFC972B2FFF  00013000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * System.ni                      00007FFC87BB0000  00007FFC887F3FFF  00c44000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * System.Core.ni                 00007FFC86130000  00007FFC86B7FFFF  00a50000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * System.Data                    00007FFC7F8A0000  00007FFC7FC07FFF  00368000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * System.Transactions            00007FFC7F640000  00007FFC7F68EFFF  0004f000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * System.Security.ni             00007FFC7AE00000  00007FFC7AEF2FFF  000f3000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * System.Xml.ni                  00007FFC80580000  00007FFC80E0BFFF  0088c000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * wldp                           00007FFC9BDE0000  00007FFC9BE04FFF  00025000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * System.Configuration.ni        00007FFC7F770000  00007FFC7F89AFFF  0012b000
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *     P1Home: 0000000000000008:  
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *     P2Home: 0000FFFF00001FA8:  
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *     P3Home: 00000000000000FE:  
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *     P4Home: 00007FFC9C45A56F:  5F00000080C48148  42850F04A8C35D5B  F68545D78BFFFFFF  4B8BFFFFFF378E0F  08408B49078B4D28  0490840F10403949  
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *     P5Home: 000000391D7F6330:  0000000000000005  000000391D7F62C0  0000000000000000  00007FFC8D5E151C  000000391D7F6AD8  0000000000000032  
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *     P6Home: 000000391D7F6270:  000001B929A93670  000000391D7F6BE0  000001B929A93670  00007FFC9C45A2F1  0048000000310020  00007FFC9C5095A8  
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * ContextFlags: 000000000010004F:  
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *      MxCsr: 0000000000001FA8:  
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *      SegCs: 0000000000000033:  
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *      SegDs: 000000000000002B:  
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *      SegEs: 000000000000002B:  
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *      SegFs: 0000000000000053:  
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *      SegGs: 000000000000002B:  
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *      SegSs: 000000000000002B:  
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *     EFlags: 0000000000000202:  
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *        Rax: 0000000000000000:  
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *        Rcx: 0000000000000000:  
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *        Rdx: 00009C29FF1CBC79:  
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *        Rbx: 0000000000000000:  
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *        Rsp: 000000391D7F6990:  000000391D7F6BE0  0000000000000000  000000391D7F6BE0  000001B929A93670  00000000000042AC  0000000000000000  
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *        Rbp: 000001B929A93670:  000001B929A93670  000001B929A91D80  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000002  
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *        Rsi: 000000391D7F6BE0:  000001AC0B084110  00007FFC8B2C863C  0000000000000001  0000000000000001  000001B959D02160  0000000000000000  
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *        Rdi: 000001B929A93670:  000001B929A93670  000001B929A91D80  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000002  
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *         R8: 00007FFC9C45A2F1:  4100000540C48148  C35D5F5D415E415F  F6854D2A74E4854D  0679DB85FF339D74  8B4893EB3F894166  850FC63B49582444  
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *         R9: 0048000000310020:  
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *        R10: 00007FFC9C5095A8:  0000003030302B65  6156746553736C46  000000000065756C  616974696E496F52  00000000657A696C  0000000000000009  
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *        R11: 0000000000000000:  
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *        R12: 000000000000002F:  
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *        R13: 0000000000000000:  
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *        R14: 00007FFC8B4AA110:  0074005F00780065  0069006D00720065  006F00740061006E  0020002D00200072  007400730061004C  0061006800630020  
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *        R15: 0000000000000000:  
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      *        Rip: 00007FFC9CE996C9:  8C8B480000441F0F  CC3348000000C024  C481480004E822E8  246483C3000000D8  CCCCCCCCD0EB0038  CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC  
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * *******************************************************************************
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-01-18 10:15:18.57 spid58      * Short Stack Dump
2021-01-18 10:15:18.58 spid58      00007FFC9CE996C9 Module(KERNELBASE+00000000000396C9)
2021-01-18 10:15:18.58 spid58      00007FFC8C7D6C1E Module(sqllang+0000000000FE6C1E)
2021-01-18 10:15:18.58 spid58      00007FFC8C7DABAA Module(sqllang+0000000000FEABAA)
2021-01-18 10:15:18.59 spid58      00007FFC8BB7D959 Module(sqllang+000000000038D959)
2021-01-18 10:15:18.59 spid58      00007FFC8B31061F Module(sqldk+000000000005061F)
2021-01-18 10:15:18.60 spid58      00007FFC9C4BDE58 Module(ucrtbase+000000000006DE58)
```

I've added my dumps here and the output of WinDbg lmv text here : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fkcsdrb7iu5b1oi/AACa9VMgZ4CWzyhnLNL7W0Saa?dl=0

---

Update : Disabling the broker have fixed the problem. However, I cannot keep it this way as we use the broker in production. I think I'll have no choice but to contact Microsoft on this one.

Comment: I would open a case with Microsoft. If you want to try to analyze the stack dump by yourself here is a resource I can recommend [this](https://github.com/arvindshmicrosoft/SQLCallStackResolver/) tool.

Comment: I already analyzed the dump with WinDbg. It's a KERNEL BASE EXCEPTION. When I go to Microsoft's website they refer to dba.stackexchange. The other option is to pay to open a case...

Comment: there [used to be a way to upload memory dumps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sql_server_team/sql-server-diagnostics-preview), but it got pulled because of gdpr or something. your alternative is to file an issue on [user voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server).

Comment: The stack trace seems to suggest the problem is in Service Broker. Is one running on the  instance? Can you disable it to see, if it makes crashes go away?

Comment: FYI - "kernel base exception" is kind of a red herring.  That's just [the Windows API call for raising an error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-raiseexception).  It looks like SQL Server raised an error after attempting to acquire a latch.  To add to the confusion, the error handling code encountered a second error, which is why you see `KERNELBASE!RaiseException` in the stack twice.

Comment: @DaniellePaquette-Harvey - do you have any antivirus, auditing, or monitoring software?  Some of these load DLLs into SQL Server process. Can check what is loaded in process in memory dump using lm command.  Please again open memory dump in Windbg, execute lmv (can take some minutes to complete) and post output. If there are 3rd party modules, does issue still happen when those are removed?  If so, please open support case.

Comment: What happens if you set startup to `Automatic (Delayed Start)`? This means it waits for network

Comment: @rois Yes Broker is enabled. I've just disabled it to see if it helps. My server crashed last night also.

Comment: I edited the question, I added the dumps and the output of WinDbg_lmv to my dropbox. Thanks for your help, as I've said, I've disabled Broker this morning so I'll see if it helps.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fkcsdrb7iu5b1oi/AACa9VMgZ4CWzyhnLNL7W0Saa?dl=0

Comment: And no antivirus, no auditing. The only monitoring software we have is Zabbix. It's been running on all of our servers without problems for years.

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this problem?

Comment: Not yet, but I can confirm it is related to the broker. I'm doing tests on another server right now. Do you have the same problem?

Comment: Do you have any XE traces capturing latch_suspend_begin and/or latch_suspend_end by chance?  if so, does disabling those resolve issue?

Comment: No I don't have XE capturing latch_suspend_begin and/or latch_suspend_end. I only have system health and telemetry_xevent and they don't include those. So far, the only thing resolving my issue is disabling the SQLBroker

Comment: I've had the same problem testing on another server with SQL 2019 standard so it's not related to the Developer's edition.

Comment: Just to add an update, we still don't have a solution to make the broker work on SQL 2019 so we decided to stick to SQL 2016 for our production environments until it gets fixed by Microsoft.

Comment: Exactly the same incident around here.
Trying all possible configuration alternatives for months. No solutions so far.

Comment: @gustavo.sdo I didn't have time to try the newest cumulative updates but this problem is preventing me from migrating to SQL 2019

Comment: @DaniellePaquette-Harvey We updated to the latest CU 11 (KB5003249) recently and noticed that errors keep happening unfortunately. The database service keeps restarting constantly.

Comment: @gustavo.sdo Please do tell me if you eventually find an easy way to reproduce it or if you contact Microsoft. I'm searching for an easy way to reproduce it so I could open a bug at Microsoft.

Comment: @DaniellePaquette-Harvey
I finally managed to solve the problem. After exhausting months of trying... The problem happened intermittently, that is, in random executions of OPENQUERY operations on linked servers, the service crashed. Which made it difficult to figure out what exactly was causing the failure.

Comment: I have multiple MySQL 5.7 databases linked on my SQL Server.
I had tested all available connectors from version 5.3 and they all had the same flaw (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-odbc/en/news-5-3.html). However, I had not tested the 8.0 releases (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-odbc/en/news-8-0.html)... After installing version 8.0.25, I had no more problems with the database.

Comment: If your environment depends on any third-party package, it probably should be to blame for the crash. Check for updated versions of these dependencies.... I was lucky to test MySQL ODBC version 8.0.25 and it works fine with my MySQL 5.7.... I checked version 8.0.26 and it didn't work correctly.

Comment: Okay thanks. I don't have third-party packages. I connect directly via our application. I hope I find someday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft finally fixed the problem with SQL Broker in SQL 2019.

BUG 14288658

> Fixes an issue where SQL Server 2019 stops responding and crashes due
> to "ex_terminator - Last chance exception handling" when you use SQL
> Server Service Broker.

The fix is available in SQL2019 CU14